# Foreground process in docker.io container

Tags: docker

I was run container from image, and processes running on foreground.

Next, I try attach shell of container.
Succussed attach, but I can not control it.

Becuase I accessed foreground process shell,
and I can't change foreground application to background.

1. docker run -i [container name] => Container id 700xxxxxxx
2. docker attach 700 => Success, but can't control it. I can only read messages from foreground process.
3. I tried 'Ctrl + Z' in order to change process states. but can't.

I want work in docker container's shell.

Anyone have solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use this command to control docker container in shell mode:

```
docker exec -it 700xxxxxxx bash
```

Comment: Awesome! You're my angel.